# Transaction is not submitting using bitcore-explorers.js

Tags: bitcoin-core, sendrawtransaction, insight-api

I'm submitting a transaction using bitcore-explorers library of js which also uses insight services of bitcoin node and here i'm receiving the error[image]

Please help me out from this error, furthermore it was working fine before couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've searched for the error on the Internet, and here's what [I found](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15780#issuecomment-334496907).

> EAI_AGAIN means the DNS server replied that it cannot currently fulfill the request

In addition, I used the BitPay BCH testnet explorer yesterday, the previous day, and the previous day. The last three days except today, the server was down and I saw "CloudFlare server down" message on the explorer's page. So, I guess they are moving the IP address behind CloudFlare's proxy, and the transition is not perfect.

Summary: It's not your mistake, but you could try [flushing DNS cache](https://askubuntu.com/a/929478).